# React change file without rebuild and restart

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I create a tiny project based on node.js express and react.

My project structure is very simple

[image]

And I run node as the server and all the react code winthin `client` folder.

my node `package.json` look like as below:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "server": "node ./bin/www",
    "client": "node start-client.js",
    "lint:client": "(cd ./client && npm run lint)",
    "lint:app": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx --ignore-pattern 'client/*'",
    "lint": "npm run lint:client && npm run lint:app",
    "dev:client": "(cd ./client && npm start)",
    "dev:app": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "build": "(cd ./client && npm run build)",
    "test:client": "(cd ./client && CI=true npm test)",
    "test:app": "jest --forceExit",
    "test": "npm run test:client && npm run test:app",
    "coverage:client": "cd ./client && npm test -- --coverage",
    "coverage:app": "jest --coverage",
    "coverage": "npm run coverage:client && npm run coverage:app",
    "install": "(cd ./client && npm install --quiet)"
  },
```

and `package.json` in client looks like as below:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "lint:scss": "stylelint 'src/**/*.scss' --syntax scss",
    "lint:scss:fix": "stylefmt --recursive 'src/**/*.scss'",
    "lint:js": "eslint . --ignore-path .gitignore --ext .js,.jsx",
    "lint:js:fix": "npm run lint:js -- --fix",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js && npm run lint:scss",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

and I run `npm start` in the root folder to start both node.js and react build.

My problem is that I need to rerun `npm start` while I change any react code.

So, my question is there any way could watch my code changes and no need to restart
while file changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are asking how you can edit your code and have it live reload, I suggest using `nodemon`. Check out the github page: https://github.com/remy/nodemon.

I have a similar project, I handled the live reload by utilizing `concurrently` in my `package.json` script:

```
"scripts": {
        "serve": "nodemon index.js",
        "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run serve\" \"npm run client\""
    }
```

the `--prefix client` refers to the name of my react directory. the `client` script runs the basic `npm run start` of my react server, while the `dev` script runs Both that and my backend.

Comment: Thanks, man, I've searched this before, and I'm trying it, but what about react part?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding the original post. Let me update my answer

Comment: hi, it opens a new tab. can't we open in the same tab?